# Make container 100% height despite no content

Tags: html, css

http://swimclub-theme.myshopify.com/search?q=asfsf

I'm using the [following theme](http://swimclub-theme.myshopify.com/search?q=asfsf). As you can see when you search for something that isn't available the page isn't 100% high the 'footer' part hangs out around the center of the page. Is there a way to make it so the container is always 100% high? I tried adding min-height and such but it doesn't seem to want to budge.

Does anyone have any idea why it's stuck like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mess with the content height. 
What you are looking for is called "sticky footer". The following is best practice CSS-only solution :

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 400px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 260px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Source: http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

You could make the html and body have a min height of 100%. If the footer is put to bottom it will then be able to go there.

```
html, body {
min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: @miro For what reason?

Comment: Because setting the body,html height does not tell the footer to go to the bottom. CSS element "stack" under each other. You must position the footer absolutely and give the body same `margin-bottom` as footer height.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before asking here and yeah, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As you said this wont work. The only thing you can do in css is to set 
`position: absolute;` http://jsfiddle.net/52vpw2wg/1/

But you can do it with JavaScript or jQuery. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/52vpw2wg/2/

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using js for sticky footer

Comment: you mean fixed footer, whats mean sticky footer?